# fixed nav bar with floats, dropdown menus, left and right margins incorrect

Tags: html, css

I've got a fixed nav bar at the top of the page.

Inside is a few floated divs that house links that when clicked toggle hidden content that slides down the main content using jQuery.

Everything works, but for some reason I can't get the dropdown menus or the content to hit margin 0 to the left and right.

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6zk25m5/2/)

And here is the CSS :

```
.wrapper { width: 100%; margin:0;padding:0;}
.topnav {width:100%;height:50px;position: fixed; top:0;background:yellow;left:0;}
.div1 {float:left;width:50px;background:blue;height:50px;}
.div2 {float:left;height:50px;background:orange;}
.div3 {float:right;width:50px;background:red;height:50px;text-align:center;}
.div4 {float:right;width:50px;background:black;height:50px;}

.link {margin:0.2rem;}

.dropdown {display:none;width:100%;background:black;color:white;}
.umenu {display:none;width:100%;background:black;color:white;}

.clear {clear:both;}

p {padding:10px 0 10px 0}

.content {margin-top:50px;background:teal;}
```

I won't bother posting the html and jQuery as I'm sure that this is strictly a CSS issue, but it's all there in the fiddle.

Comment: If I can understand you want the dropdown content to have the same dimensions as the top menu, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiot.... I hadn't set the body margins to 0 in the fiddle.

Working now!

I'll leave it here unless somebody else finds it useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution.

You can change `position:realtive`

```
 .content {margin-top:50px;background:teal;margin-top:-15px;} /*MODIFICATION*/

.topnav {width:100%;height:50px;position: relative; top:0;background:yellow;left:0;} /* MODIFICATION*/
```

here's Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L6zk25m5/4/